# Get CSS DIV to fill all height between other DIVs

Tags: html, css

I have a modal dialog for a workflow that displays content roughly of a fixed height, but also displays an embedded PDF for a user to review.

I'd like to maximize the height of the PDF for the user's screen size, so the dialog scales vertically, but I can't get the PDF to fill all the remaining space within the dialog's div.

Here is the Html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="popUp">
        <div class="popUpHeader">Header</div>
        <div class="fixedContent">Fixed Height Content</div>
        <div class="resizeableContent">I should fill all the free vertical space in .popUp</div>
        <div class="popUpFooter">Footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS I'm using:

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.container {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: #F8F8FF;
}
.popUp {
    background: lightgrey;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 70%;
    height: 90%;
}
.popUpHeader {
    width: 100%;
    background: darkgrey;
    text-align: center;
}
.popUpFooter {
    width:100%;
    background:darkgrey;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
.fixedContent {
    height: 10em;
    text-align: center;
    background: #E1E1EE;
}
.resizeableContent {
    background: #7d7f7c;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100% height: 100%;
}
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/trainman1124/pnbeoyb9/2/

Here is an image of the desired result: [image]

**Edit**

Here is a sample JsFiddle using an embedded PDF, which is what actually needs to be done.
http://jsfiddle.net/trainman1124/pnbeoyb9/3/

Note, I've corrected the missing semicolon in the example and also added overflow:hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `display: table;` and `display: table-row` properties in order to fill the space.

Set the `.container` to fill 100% of the page and `.popUp` div to `display: table;` and fill it's parent.

Display all the children as `display: table-row;`, and then set heights for the `popUpHeader` and `popUpFooter` divs.

Allow your `resizableContent` div to fill the remaining space:

```
.resizeableContent {
    background: #7d7f7c;
    width: 100% height: 100%;
    display: table-row;
}
```

Check out this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/JRKyte/pen/CcrjA)

Comment: This is a great solution, I placed an update to my original fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/trainman1124/tz8cw8s3/

Answer (score 0):

The updated fiddle has the heights set to % instead. That works as you want I think?

**Update** 
http://jsfiddle.net/batcave/pnbeoyb9/7/

```
.popUpFooter {
    width:100%;
    background:darkgrey;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 7%;
}

.resizeableContent {
    background: #7d7f7c;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
}

.fixedContent {
    height: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #E1E1EE;
}
```

Comment: That's pretty close, but since we are hiding the overflow, we lose the controls as the bottom of the PDF viewer.

Here is a sample JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/trainman1124/pnbeoyb9/3/

Comment: @Nick updated my answer. Your issue is with heights. It can be fixed with javascript. It can be fixed with css also. Answer my questions above.

Comment: The updated fiddle might work, but it isn't ideal since the size of the fixed content would change as the window height changes.

Sadly the "fixed content" isn't 100% fixed, but it doesn't change size by too much.

I only need to support the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: The footer can be a fixed height.

Comment: @Nick updated my answer. I think this could work for you. Just make small adjustments for your needs there with the `.fixedContent`, and of cause doing that you would have to reduce the height of `. resizeableContent`

Comment: There is one issue, that it doesn't auto-fit the fixedContent class. Our users run this app full screen from laptops to 30" monitors. If I make it look right for our users on 30" monitors (our primary users), it won't look right for users on a laptop with almost half the vertical resolution.

Comment: @Nick So the `.fixedContent` should get a height based on the content in it? Maybe you should update your question a bit so it's more clear. It's not so hard to solve once the instructions are right.

Answer (score 0):

Modify Popup class to make its color same as resiseableContent

`.popUp {
    background: #7d7f7c; /* Modified here */
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 70%;
    height: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
}`

Comment: resizableContent should actually be 100% filled with a PDF, so that won't work. I've provided an updated JsFiddle in my question.

It does fill the full area using overflow: hidden, but that hides the browser controls that let you save or print the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what browsers you need to support (This wont work earlier than IE9), one solution would be to use `calc` and `vh` units.

Something like:

```
.popUp {
    background: lightgrey;
    margin: auto;
    height: calc(100vh - 10em); /* Height of viewport minus your .fixedContent div, you may also want to include the height of the header */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I like the approach, it does give me a few ideas. For my example I set the fixed content div to 10em, but if you read my question I stated, "content roughly of a fixed height", so it isn't really fixed in the actual site, but it doesn't change by much. The footer could be set to a fixed height though.

Comment: @Nick Ok, check my other answer, see if that's better for you (solves the problem of having a variable height for the .fixedContent div)